# How to match a repeated character sequence with Regular Expression (regex)

Tags: regex

I want to capture all repeated numbers groups

- if i have
  1115555666777
- I want to capture this
  (111)(5555)(666)(777)
- I feel this is not the best way to achive what i want
  any idea to improve this regex?
- `[1]+|[2]+|[3]+|[4]+|[5]+|[6]+|[7]+|[8]+|[9]+`

Comment: This regex already makes what i want but i think it's pretty large

Comment: you can also write it like `([1-9])\1+` and tell me if its not working...

Comment: Or if you also want to match single occurrences `([0-9])\1*`

Comment: when i execute this regex I got what i wanted but another "groups" what do those groups means?

Comment: You get a single captured value that is group 1, but you do get 4 times a whole match that has all the repeated values.  See https://regex101.com/r/c9EvkA/1 Then capture value is highlighted in green, and the match information shows the separate matches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you,
the answer that worked for me was:
`([0-9])\1*`
Thanks, again :D

Comment: It sounds like @TheFourthBird answered your question, you should "check" the check mark on their post to accept that as the answer.

Comment: for regex engines that don't offer back-references, one alternate method would be to do gsub("0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+", "&_"), then split the resulting string into an array using "_" as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group for a single digit `([1-9])` and optionally repeat a backreference `\1*` containing the same value as the group.

The optional part `*` is due to that in your pattern you repeat the number 1 or more times. The 1 time you already have in the capture group.

The pattern:

```
[1]+|[2]+|[3]+|[4]+|[5]+|[6]+|[7]+|[8]+|[9]+
```

Can be written as

```
1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+
```

Can be written as

```
([1-9])\1*
```

Or if the zero is also allowed, can be written as:

```
([0-9])\1*
```

See a [regex demo for digits 1-9](https://regex101.com/r/FGNpDJ/1)